# Escrita de arquivo em sistema multithread em c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, sistema-operacional

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema no qual me encontro no seguinte cenário: um programa precisa criar um arquivo parte a parte. Ele recebe bytes de um servidor e assim o arquivo é criado, ele deve funcionar desse modo pois é uma decisão de projeto.

O problema é que mais de uma thread pode acabar gravando esses bytes, logo creio que isso ocasionaria em uma condição de corrida. A maneira que lidei para contornar esse problema foi a implementação dessa classe:

```
internal class ConcurrentFile
{
    private readonly object _padlock = new object();
    public string Path { get; set; }

    public ConcurrentFile(string path)
    {
        Path = path;
    }

    public void CreateEmpty()
    {
        lock (_padlock)
        {
            File.Create(Path).Dispose();
        }
    }

    public void Write(byte[] data)
    {
        lock (_padlock)
        {
            using(var fileStream = new FileStream(Path, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write))
            {
                fileStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                fileStream.Flush();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Essa é uma solução problemática? Quais problemas poderei ter? Aliás, esse código é realmente seguro? Me ajudem a encontrar uma boa solução! Grato pela atenção dos senhores.

Comment: Vejo vários problemas nesse código. Na prática nem está obtendo as vantagens que espera ter, concorrência é muito difícil de fazer certa. Quer saber? Coloca no SQLite, provavelmente terá melhor performance e certamente mais robustez.

Comment: @Maniero, fiz uns testes com o código e aparentemente o lock está controlando bem a concorrência.  Você poderia explicar quais são os tipos de problemas encontrados?

Comment: Se você fez teste e viu que está bom você é mais especialista em concorrência que eu, não tem como eu possa ajudá-lo. Eu acho que não testou tão bem quanto acha. Tem gente que é especialista nisso e não consegue testar totalmente.

Comment: @Maniero, Quero saber quais foram os problemas que você encontrou... Sua ótica sobre o assunto pode ajudar na pergunta em questão.

Comment: @Maniero Agradeço sua resposta, mas você poderia abrir uma resposta detalhando os problemas? Ter esse conhecimento seria muito útil pra mim, e acredito também que ajudará outras pessoas que podem cair nessa pergunta com problemas similares.

Comment: Não porque a pergunta não é sobre isto e se fosse seria muito ampla, e piora o fato de você achar que sabe o que está fazendo. O que posso te dizer é que é melhor você fazer com SQLite, eu mexo com isso há décadas e faria assim porque é mais fácil fazer certo. Se desejar aprender fazer concorrência certo aqui não é o local certo, precisa aprender todos os fundamentos para chegar no conhecimento, precisa ir exercitando uma coisa atrás da outra, passo por passo, sem pular nada, aqui é para dúvidas pontuais.